# can anyone explain where have i done something wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this code it shows parse error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
 $servername = "localhost";    
$username = "root";      
$password = "";      
$dbname = "form";    

 // Create connection      
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,$password, $dbname);          
// Check connection      
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);      
}  
 SELECT * FROM my_db;    
 $conn->close();
```

Comment: Perhaps it's all those '>' signs

Comment: Were you trying to run SQL commands in php script? All those `>` signs

Answer (score 1):

You should use php tags and remove those ">" also you should use mysqli_query to query the data from mysql

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";    
$username = "root";      
$password = "";      
$dbname = "form";    

 // Create connection      
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,$password, $dbname);          
// Check connection      
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);      
}  
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM my_db");    
$conn->close();
?>
```